# How to not reach the sharepoint error page?

Tags: 2010, url, redirect, error-handling

I have a link that redirect users on the 'unexpected error is occured' page when they type a wrong code and submit it. If the code is valide the redirection is done and they reach the correct page.

I would like to know how to check weither the redirected page will be the 'unexpected error is occured' page or the correct one.

[image]

Comment: Can you add some sharepoint logs with correlation token "f0fac31c-..."?

Comment: I don't want to fix the error because I perfectly know why it is occuring. I just don't want to reach this page. Instead, I would prefer to display a message to users. I have to say that I've already checked  the html error codes. It doesn't matter which one is triggered because sharepoint will redirect to this page anyway. So I need to handle the rediection result before.

Answer (score 1):

In theory there is two ways to do what you're asking:

- Add JavaScript into the page doing the post which intercepts the post, performs it in the background and redirect the user based on the result.
- Add a Http Module to your SharePoint farm which intercepts the redirect on the way out and the redirect you to another page (but which)

But I'd recommend that you instead try to add JavaScript to validate the user input and then not do the post if not valid. If it's a standard SharePoint Form then the validation can be done in PreSaveAction (see [Marc D Andersons:Validation on SharePoint Forms – Part Four](http://sympmarc.com/2009/05/28/validation-on-sharepoint-forms-part-four/) )

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't know which values are correct before I get the error page so I cannot perform a validation trick. I have no choice. I have to trying to open the page, check if it failed then display a message to user.

Comment: If you really don't know the valid values then the best option would be to do the get/post from JavaScript and show error message if you get error page and redirect otherwise, this requests the page twice, but ...